# What does mv !(old-project) old-project do?

Tags: bash, shell

I am reading this blog post https://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2011/09/12/moving-one-git-repo-into-another-as-subdirectory/, where the author uses the command `mv !(old-project) old-project`.

What does it do ?

My guess is that it copies all contents of `old-project` to the `old-project` subfolder except the `old-project` subfolder itself. How does it do that though ?

Comment: It fails ;-) This is not good bash syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash performs [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) occording to the rules in [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching). The `!(old-project)` matches everything except `old-project`.

```
!(pattern-list)

    Matches anything except one of the given patterns.
```

If `old-project` exists and is a directory and there are files or folders or others inside the current working directory named other then `old-project`: Then `mv !(old-project) old-project` moves all files and directories in the current working directory in the `old-project` folder in the current working directory.

Corner cases:

- if `old-project` does not exists, `mv` will fail with `mv: target 'old-project' is not a directory`
- if `old-project` exists and is not a directory (and not a symplink to a directory, etc), then `mv` will fail with same as above error.
- if there are no files and no directories etc. in the current working directory except `old-project`, or `old-project` is missing too, then `mv` will fail with `mv: cannot stat '!(old-project)': No such file or directory`, as the `!(old-project)` will not expand.

Basically, `!(old-project)` expands to everything except `old-project`. In terminal I often just do `mv * old-project` and watch `mv` fail with the "can't move same dir to itself" error. In scripts using `!(old-project)` is a alternative.

Note that for `!(pattern-list)` to work in bash, the `extglob` shell option has to be enabled using the `shopt` builtin.